# What should I look out when using `IPAddress.Any`?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

What are the disadvantages of using `IPAddress.Any`?

Is there any Gotchu's? For e.g in a network if another service or app is using port 5000 by listening on port 5000, does listening affect other apps e.g. kicks them off the port? what if the request is frequency(does it affects anything else on port 5000? is it a good idea to use port 5000` is it reserved?

I am using `IPAddress.Any` because of this error:

> The requested address is not valid in its context

```
listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, PORT_NO);
listener.Start();
notDone = true;
string allClip = "";
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.WriteLine("Waiting to receive commands from the data path generator plugin");
string test = "";

while (notDone)
{


    Console.ResetColor();

    Socket client = listener.AcceptSocket();

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    var childSocketThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        //Code here
    });

    childSocketThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: IP address should be valid except under two cases 1) The port is already being used by another application 2) If you are using IPV6 then use             IPAddress.IPv6Any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`What are the disadvantages of using IPAddress.Any?`

Probably security issues (publishing your app on every available interface)

If something already listens on port 5000 you won't be able to bind to that port. (You should pick a port from 49152 through 65535 (Dynamic and/or Private
Ports (49152-65535)) - you can check the registered ports [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml))

Comment: Thanks, Can you elaborate on your last point, please? If a different app on the same network on a different IP uses the same port? It won't allow me? what is my app was loaded first will it stops another service because this is what I am trying to prevent! because my app is the least import on the network. How can I make sure my port is unique? or is there another solution for the error above other than `IPAddress.Any`?

Comment: The connection is defined by the socket (which is an IP address and a port number together) - so if somebody else's computer listens on the same port, nothing will happen on your computer. If you can bind to the socket(ip port pair), then you are good to go, if an exception is thrown then you have to choose another port)

Comment: IPAddress.Any will return the address 0.0.0.0 which means "listen on all available interfaces". You can provide some valid ip address (for example your machine local ip, or the loopback (127.0.0.1) interface), but in this case you will be able to connect to that ip.

Comment: What was the address you provided instead of `IPAddress.Any`?

Comment: The address starts with `10.`, Does the connection gets block if you are listening(no sending just receiving)?? So cant multiple computer on one network listen to one port on a single network?

Comment: Inversely, computers on the same network can listen on the same port (because their address (ip) differs). For example.: PC1 (IP:192.168.0.1:5000) PC2(IP:192.168.0.2:5000) This is OK. What you can't is listen on the same port on the same computer, for example: PC1 (192.168.0.1:5000) PC1(192.168.0.1:5000 <- this will not work, because there is already something listening on that port)

Comment: @C1sc0 what about _ExclusiveAddressUse_ (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Ok, Thanks it s much clearer now. My final question now will be: When Using `IPAddress.Any`  which of the two scenario `IPAddress.Any` comes under? PC1 (IP:192.168.0.1:5000) PC2(IP:192.168.0.2:5000) or PC1 (192.168.0.1:5000) PC1(192.168.0.1:5000, What am concerned about is kicking off another service by listening using  `IPAddress.Any`

Comment: (PC1 (192.168.0.1:5000) PC1(192.168.0.1:5000)) You can run any app on any port on you local computer, it won't kick out another service from your network (You don't run you application on the PC2 there are not "connected" not using sockets from the same space) - your app can't bind on another computer network interface on the network. If you are using the `IPAddress.Any` it just on your local computer.

Comment: To conclude, binding issues only occur when its the same IP and port?

Comment: Yes, you are right! Try to start the same application on the same machine twice, the second will fail.

Comment: Yes, I tried, thanks it wont allow me to, I was just worried about other devices getting denied  because of my app with low priority. (I am only receiving data)

Comment: @dfhwze If the ReuseAddress option is set, then the socket could be bound to that interface and port already in use by another socket. To prevent this, you can use the ExclusiveAddressUse property (by setting it to true).